# Canonical link in php

Tags: php, canonical-link

Hy there!

I have a problem to understand canonical links: I have a page on my website that gets in the url, into a parameter source, the site where the users was before, but only if he comes from adwords. Otherwise I don't have any parameter and I want to verify if there is or there isn't that parameter and send the right link with canonical. I realise that I am not very clear in my explain, but that is because I don't know exactly how to use the canonical link. If you can make me understand, please do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take some time an rephrase your question please. Maybe you'll get lucky and somebody will take a lucky guess at what you mean, but I at least have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: I think, you can easly use google to find this link with perfect explanation: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394

Comment: So it's that hard to say it nicely? Thanks for down votes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given a brief explaination of canonical links as from your question, about all I get is that you want to understand how to use them...

The canonical link is an HTML element you put in the `<head>` section of a particular webpage as part of an SEO effort.

It tells search engines what link to use to refer to the page if multiple different links all point to the same page.

For example:

If `page.html` can be reached from the following URL's

- www.domain.com/page.html
- www.domain.com/page.html?order=asc
- page.domain.com

You may want to set a canonical link in the header to ensure that only one of these is sent back to the search engine for SEO purposes

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.domain.com/page.html" />
    </head>
</html>
```

However, it should be noted that this is a *hint* and not a directive and so web spiders from search engines will not necessarily follow the link guidance.